# Toggle CSS Class on Event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a block of HTML that looks like this:

```
<div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#groupOptions" data-target="#group" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="group" class="collapsable-group-header">
  <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right toggle"></span> Group</h3>
</div>
```

This HTML is using Bootstrap's [collapse control](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse). The behavior works fine. I'm now trying to change the glyphicon from right to down. To do that, I have the following:

```
$('#group')
  .on('show.bs.collapse', function () { 
    var $toggle= $('#group > .toggle');
    $toggle.removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
    $toggle.addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    console.log($toggle.html());
  })
  .on('hide.bs.collapse', function() { alert('hiding...'); })
;
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. My console.log statements are printing `undefined`. Yet, if I do `console.log($toggle)` I see an element. What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: is the alert working?...

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
$('#group > .toggle');
```

To

```
$('[data-target=#group] .toggle');
```

I don't see anything with an id set to `group`.

Also, `.toggle` isn't the *immediate* child of the parent so get rid of `>`.

Answer (score 0):

The result returned by jQuery is an array. Use $toggle[0].removeClass... instead.

Comment: If your intention is to target a single element that is... :-)